# How do I make a service method that invokes another service method transactional?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, annotations

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JPA 2.0, and MySQL 5.5  I define transactions within my Spring application context file like so:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/springboard/sbpersistence" id="entityManagerFactory"
                 expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

I have a Spring service class that has the following methods:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService
{

        @Override
        public User create(String firstName,
                   String middleName,
                   String lastName,
                   String userName,
                   String password,
                   String url,
                   Role role,
                   Organization org,
                   final Set<Contract> contracts)
        {
            …
            return userDao.save(user);
        }

        @Override
        public User createSampleUser(String firstName,
                             String middleName,
                             String lastName,
                             String userName,
                             String password,
                             String url,
                             Role role,
                             State state,
                             List<Product> products,
                             Date activationDate,
                             Date expirationDate)
        {        
            …
            return create(firstName,
                  middleName,
                  lastName,
                  userName,
                  password,
                  url,
                  role,
                  sampleDistrict,
                  contracts);
        }
```

Notice that the second method invokes the first service method.  My question is what is the appropriate annotation, if any, to indicate what I want everything within the second method to be treated as an atomic unit of work?  I was confused since my first method is automatically @Transactional.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updates based on comment**

---

You can annotate the `create()` method with a propagation of `REQUIRED`:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public User create(String firstName,
               String middleName,
               String lastName,
               String userName,
               String password,
               String url,
               Role role,
               Organization org,
               final Set<Contract> contracts)
    {
        …
        return userDao.save(user);
    }
```

`REQUIRED` means that if there is a current transaction, it will use that same transaction.  Otherwise, it will create a new transaction for the method to execute in.  The javadoc for `REQUIRED` :

> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.  Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.  This is the default setting of a transaction annotation.

Based on the last comment of the javadoc, this is the default transaction propagation setting,  so technically you shouldn't need the annotation, but I nearly always put it in so that it's clear (incase the default changes as well!).

Comment: Hi, That's the opposite of waht I was looking for.  When I said, "I want everything within the second method to be treated as an atomic unit of work," I meant that I want the transaction to be the stuff the second method does + the first method as opposed to 2 transactions -- the second method doing some stuff and then invoking the first method.  Does it make sense what I'm asking?